# C#, Why I am still getting a powershell output result even though it never assigned?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell-3.0

I commented out the powershell output result assigning to str. I am still getting the powershell output in ResultBox which it was not suppose to be. Could it be bugged? I tried debugger and it couldn't identify functions...

Here is the C# code:

```
protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clean the Result TextBox
    ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;
    ResultBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");

    string str = "";

    // Powershell
    Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runSpace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

    Command invokeScript = new Command("Invoke-Command");
    RunspaceInvoke invoke = new RunspaceInvoke();

    // invoke-command -computername compName -scriptblock { get-process }

    ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke("{"+ PowerShellCodeBox.Text +"}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
    invokeScript.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb);
    invokeScript.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

    pipeline.Commands.Add(invokeScript);
    Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();

    foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
    {

        //str = str + psObject;
        //str = psObject + "\r\n";
        //str += "\n" + psObject;
        //str = str + Environment.NewLine + psObject;
    }

    if (str == ""){
        str = "Error";

        ResultBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
    }

    ResultBox.Text = str;
}
```

Comment: Did you close your browsers and make sure you started the new version with the code commented out? You may need to do a clean on the project and rebuild it. Just two things that come to mind. Hope it helps.

Comment: You are right. But I tried rebuild and it doesn't work. So I created a new solution and copied the codes and it work just fine. Thank you for advice